# Lavazza A Modo Mio espresso drips out very slowly

Tags: espresso-machine

I have a Lavazza A Modo Mio.

Recently, the espresso extract has been dripping out really slowly and it takes about 10-15 minutes to fill half a cup. I tried to clean the machine like the manual says (operate without a capsule - just on water), although this is something I do on a weekly basis, just to maintain my machine.

I have had this machine since April 2012. Could it be that it is too old?

Comment: My machine us only 3 months old and I'm having the same problem with the coffe dribbling out it used to be fantastic so whats going on,can anyone help or dies it go back to the shop

Comment: I have the opposite problem. It gushes out too quickly and there isn't enough flavour in the cup.
Peter

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your machine needs to be descaled.

I pulled this from the documentation on their [website](http://www.lavazza.com/default/.content/document/pdf/manuali/manuale_favola_plus_aeg.pdf).

> Your machine will need descaling on a regular basis (approximately every 3 months) to
>   ensure it is working efficiently and to prevent any major technical faults developing. This is a simple process and will have immediate results.

The good news is if you can get water through it you can get it going again. The descaled works by desolving the calcium deposits in the machine and letting the water flow freely again.

Comment: I am having the same experience as the OP with my Lavazza A Modo Mio AEG Favola machine. I have descaled it several times and even immediately after descaling the rate of coffee coming through is very poor. 

My guess is that the compressor, although still working, is not working as well as it used to. So it doesn't have enough pressure to push the water through the capsule and as a result it takes a long time to make my coffee - and most of the water piles up in the reserve tray. Is this possible?